# PostgreSQL: set a column with the ordinal of the row sorted via another field

Tags: postgresql

I have a table `segnature` describing an item with a varchar field `deno` and a numeric field `ord`. A foreign key `fk_collection` tells which collection the row is part of.

I want to update field `ord` so that it contains the ordinal of that row per each collection, sorted by field deno.

E.g. if I have something like

```
[deno]     ord   [fk_collection]
abc              10
aab              10
bcd              10
zxc              20
vbn              20
```

Then I want a result like

```
[deno]     ord   [fk_collection]
abc          1   10
aab          0   10
bcd          2   10
zxc          1   20
vbn          0   20
```

I tried with something like

```
update segnature s1 set ord = (select count(*) 
    from segnature s2 
    where s1.fk_collection=s2.fk_collection and s2.deno<s1.deno
)
```

but query is *really* slow: 150 collections per about 30000 items are updated in 10 minutes about.

Any suggestion to speed up the process?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a window function to generate the "ordinal" number:

```
with numbered as (
   select deno, fk_collection, 
          row_number() over (partition by fk_collection order by deno) as rn, 
          ctid as id
   from segnature
) 
update segnature
  set ord = n.rn
from numbered n
where n.id = segnature.ctid;
```

This uses the internal column [`ctid`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/ddl-system-columns.html)  to uniquely identify each rows. The `ctid` comparison is quite slow, so if you have a real primary (or unique) key in that table, use that column instead.

Alternatively without the [common table expression](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html):

```
update segnature
  set ord = n.rn
from (
    select deno, fk_collection, 
           row_number() over (partition by fk_collection order by deno) as rn, 
           ctid as id
    from segnature
) as n
where n.id = segnature.ctid;
```

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e997f/1

Comment: Perfect :) I have also a pk_id on each row, so I adapted your query in order to use PK and now it works like a charm: about 1 second vs. 10 minutes is a _great_ improvement! I didn't know the window functions, I will have to learn how they works. A huge thank you!